# Convert opencv's surf descriptor to a matrix

Tags: opencv, surf

I'm new to C and OpenCV, I want to get the surf descriptor's data matrix.

```
double tt = (double)cvGetTickCount();
cvExtractSURF( object, 0, &objectKeypoints, &objectDescriptors, storage, params );
printf("Object Descriptors: %d\n", objectDescriptors->total);
```

If I use `cvSave(fileName, objectDescriptors)` then I can get the XML file, my question is how can I get just the matrix of descriptor of the data of objectDescriptor, for example, there are 45 keypoints, then the matrix is `A=matrix[45][64]`?

How can I get A in directly from the `objectDescriptors`?

How can I get A from the xml file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenCV new API [`SurfFeatureDetector`](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html). It will directly save keypoints to a `vector<KeyPoint>`.

```
int minHessian = 400;
SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
detector.detect( img, keypoints);
```

Check out [cv::KeyPoint Class Reference](http://physics.nyu.edu/grierlab/manuals/opencv/classcv_1_1KeyPoint.html).

Check out [[1]](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html) and [[2]](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_features2d.html) for real examples.

Comment: Hi, I see the data type of descriptor is `Mat`, how can I convert it to a array?

Comment: Descriptors of the keypoints.
`// computing descriptors
SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;
extractor.compute(img1, keypoints1, descriptors1);`

Comment: @user3200905 Use the method `detect()` in the above answer.

Comment: ? how to use? `vector<Descriptor>  detector.detect( img, descriptor)?  `. Are there any examples?

Comment: @user3200905 You can refer to the links I gave in the answer.

Comment: the method in your links is use `extractor.computer` to obtain the descriptors.